# Explanation of tables of redmine database model

Tags: database-schema, redmine, redmine-plugins

I looked at Redmine Database Model
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/DatabaseModel

And didn't find explanation of any table.
I intuitively guess the purpose of the main tables such as "issues", "projects", "users", "trackes".

I checked redmine forum topic related to my question
http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/19470
But there no information for me.

Could you please give me any explanation of next tables:

- queries
- enumerations
- workflows
- time_entries
- repositories
- changesets
- changes

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- queries are user queries with filters, sorts and columns for issues at`project\issues` tab - users with appropriate privilegies can save and modify own or common queries
- enumetations - issue importances and other text enumerations that doesn't need special entities
- workflows contains:

  - issue workflows (issue jumping through statuses - e.g. new -> resolved -> closed)
  - workflow rules (can jump from new to resolved, but can't from closed to new)
  - workflow permissions (developer can resolve issue, but only tester can close it)
- time_entries - issues has link «Log time» where users can enter spent times for issue resolving (may by several times for one issue)

And sorry, don't know other tables :)